# Weird bug when presenting a view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad

I have a basic app with a UITabBarController as the root view controller. When a user of the app is not signed in I'm showing a modal controller via `window!.rootViewController!.present(viewController, animated: true)` in my `AppDelegate`. This works fine on all iPhone models, however the following happens on any iPad:

[image: broken]

The background color of the SignInController is visible during the transition. Now comes the weird thing: When I change the view in Interface Builder to an iPad the bug is gone like so:

[image: working]

Changing the background color back to the transparent default removes at least the white background, however the view is still animating from the left bottom which is something I don't want. And by the way, changing the view in Interface Builder breaks the animation on all iPhones. Changing it back fixes it but breaks again all iPads.

This is the code (using ReSwift for state management):

```
func newState(state: State) {
  switch (previousState.session, state.session) {
  case (.loading, .notSignedIn), (.signedIn, .loading):
      (window!.rootViewController! as! UITabBarController).selectedIndex = 0

      let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignInViewController")
      window!.rootViewController!.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

  default:
    // more stuff
    break
  }
}
```

**EDIT**: Added the actual code.

Comment: “When a user of the app is not signed in, I'm showing a modal controller” The problem is _when_ you are doing that. Show your actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it!

The problem was a combination of having an observer on `keyboardWillShowNotification` and a `becomeFirstResponder` in the `viewWillAppear` method of the presented controller.

Moving the `becomeFirstResponder` into `viewDidAppear` fixed all the problems!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks man! Saved my day.. I'm presenting the keyboard from within a tableview cell - I fixed it like this:

```
private var canPresentKeyboard: Bool = false

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    canPresentKeyboard = true
    if _currentlySelectedIdType != .image {
        reload(section: .idType)
    }
}

func configure(cell: NumberIdTableViewCellInput) {
    cell.set(delegate: self)
    if canPresentKeyboard {
        cell.clearAndSetFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

I know the code is a bit out of context, but I believe the intention is clear.